# How to convert date format

Tags: java

Can any one help in conversion of date format?

My returned date object is contains `"Mon Jul 12 00:00:00 IST 2010"`

I'm trying to convert this date format to `"MM/dd/yyyy"` but I'm getting parse exception. Please help me how to convert it

---

Code from the OP's comment:

```
String mydatObj = myDate.toString(); 
Date formatedDate = getDateFormat(mydatObj); 
public static Date getDateFormat(String dateString) { 
    Date date = null; 
    SimpleDateFormat format = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy"); 
    try { 
        // set isLenient to false to adhere to the date format. 
        format.setLenient(false); 
        date = format.parse(dateString); 
    } catch (ParseException parseException) { 
        // ignore 
        LOG.error(parseException.getMessage(), parseException); 
    } 
    return date; 
}
```

Comment: Please add properly formatted code to your question

Answer (score 8):

Well, you are getting a `ParseException` since you are trying to parse a date with the wrong format.

Here is a small code snippet which *will* work with the format you have:

```
// parse the date
DateFormat f = new SimpleDateFormat("E MMM dd HH:mm:ss zzz yyyy");
Date d = f.parse("Mon Jul 12 00:00:00 IST 2010"); // works

// now print the date
DateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
System.out.println(out.format(d));
```

Comment: +1 Maybe help him out with the last part as well ;)
print the date to "MM/dd/yyyy" format.