# How to convert date?

Tags: java, primefaces

I'am using the calendar of primefaces:

```
<p:calendar  value="#{TestAjax.date1}" showOn="button" />
```

this calandar return the date with this format:

```
Fri Jul 08 00:00:00 GMT+01:00 2011
```

How can I convert this date to this format : 2011-07-08 or 2011/07/08

Thank you

**UPADTE**

I have converted the date ,below the code I hope this will help sombody else

```
DateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("MM/dd/yyyy");
String date=out.format(myDate1);
```

Comment: Have you tried anything or even search about it before posting this?

Comment: A related question that might be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235240/how-to-convert-date-format

Comment: @ razlebe,thank you it was helpfull

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let me hope following example helps you.

```
import java.util.Date;  
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;  

public class test  
{  
    public static void main( String[] args )  
    {  
        String myDatePattern1 = "yyyy-MM-dd";  
        String myDatePattern2 = "yyyy/MM/dd";  
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat( myDatePattern1 );  

        Date today = new Date();
        System.out.println( "Date today: " + today );
        System.out.println( "Date in pattern 1: " + df.format( today ) );

        df.applyPattern( myDatePattern2 );
        System.out.println( "Date in pattern 2: " + df.format( today ) );
    } // psvm(...)
} // class test
```

Output of this example would be as below:
`Date today: Sat Jul 09 16:01:23 IST 2011`
`Date in pattern 1: 2011-07-09`
`Date in pattern 2: 2011/07/09`

Answer (score 3):

You can use [SimpleDateFormat](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html) or Joda-Time's [DateTimeFormat](http://joda-time.sourceforge.net/api-release/org/joda/time/format/DateTimeFormat.html) to parse it into a date object and then use the same class also to format it to the other format.

Answer (score 0):

Use the following:

```
<p:calendar value="#{TestAjax.date1}" pattern="yyyy-dd-MM" />
```

Pattern attribute is used to change pattern of calendars.

Comment: Good answer. Please expand it by adding more about Pattern attribute  and the types and of patterns for a +1