# Convert time format in java from YYYY-MM-DD to Day-Month-Year

Tags: java

I am getting time from my database as 2013-11-01 00:00:00 which is a string. 
I want to convert it to 1 November 2013 using java.
How to do it?

Comment: Look at the related questions on the right.

Comment: Keeping such date in the database is a disaster.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to convert date format](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235240/how-to-convert-date-format)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
SimpleDateFormat sdf = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss"));
Date d = sdf.parse(input);
sdf.applyPattern("dd MM yyyy");
String output = sdf.format(d);
```

Answer (score 0):

try this way

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String dateInString = "2013-11-01 00:00:00";

    try {

        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        System.out.println(date);
        System.out.println(formatter.format(date));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

as per the comment given below

```
SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
    String dateInString = "2013-11-01 00:00:00";
    SimpleDateFormat formatter1 = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");

    try {

        Date date = formatter.parse(dateInString);
        //System.out.println(date);
        //System.out.println(formatter.format(date));
        DateFormat out = new SimpleDateFormat("dd MMM yyyy");

        System.out.println(out.format(date));

    } catch (ParseException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

**output** 01 Nov 2013

Comment: the first sysout shows Fri Nov 01 00:00:00 GMT+05:30 2013, how to get 01 November 2013?