# how to convert Date Oct 31 2015 12:00AM into 20151031 format

Tags: java, date

I tried to covert Oct 31 2015 12:00AM into yyyyMMdd format but it is giving below exception.what could be the reason and solution ?
Exception coming while running this code : **java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Oct 31 2015 12:00AM"**

```
try{
        SimpleDateFormat formatter = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd");           
        System.out.println("output : "+formatter.format(formatter.parse("Oct 31 2015 12:00AM")));
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            System.out.println("e: "+e);
    }
```

Comment: You need one `SimpleDateFormat` to `parse` and another one to `format` - what you have is the latter - now you need to work on the former. Something like: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3235240/how-to-convert-date-format

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the same formatter with `yyyyMMdd` to parse the date `Oct 31 2015 12:00AM` which is in the different format i.e. `MMMM dd yyyy hh:mma`.

You need to define a new formatter to parse the inner date correctly.

Here is a quick code snippet:

```
public static void main (String[] args)
{
    try{
        SimpleDateFormat xedFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("MMMM dd yyyy hh:mma"); 
        SimpleDateFormat pedFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd"); 
        System.out.println("output : "+pedFormat.format(xedFormat.parse("Oct 31 2015 12:00AM")));
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.println("e: "+e);
}
```

Output:

```
output : 20151031
```

Comment: Thanks mate..could you please explain the reason.

Comment: `Oct 31 2015 12:00AM` has a different format and hence can't be parse using `yyyyMMdd`. You need to define the correct format i.e. `MMMM dd yyyy hh:mma`. Once parsed it returns you the `Date` Object which can be further formatted to your desired output i.e. `yyyyMMdd`.